# Anchor with hash in href attribute is opening a new page

Tags: html, url, redirect, hash, anchor

I have never seen this behavior.  I have a simple hash link on a website.  The link looks like this:

```
<a href='#view_123'>Click</a>
```

On my test server, when I click, it simply changes the url to

```
http://www.myserver.com/mypage.aspx#view_123
```

And the page does not redirect anywhere.  However, when I push this same link to my live server, it causes the browser to redirect to:

```
http://www.myserver.com/www.myserver.com#view_123
```

This makes no sense to me.  The only way around this is to put the full url of the page in the href with the hash appended to the end, but this is causing me other problems and is not what I want to do.

The only clue I've come across is the MIME type, but I'm pretty sure mine is correct as "text/html".

There is no javascript causing this.  I can hover over the link, and the url hint in Chrome shows the incorrect url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the target tag?

```
<a href='#view_123' target='_self'>Click</a>
```

or

```
<a href='#view_123' target='_top'>Click</a>
```

Comment: The target attribute just tells the browser which tab or window to open the link in.  target="_self" means current window, and did not change the behavior in any way.  target="_top" means the top frame, but I only have one frame anyway.

Comment: I have found the problem.  In the head of my document, there was a "base" tag that was set to the domain.  

    <base href="www.myserver.com">

Base tags set the "default url" for anchors on the page, which is why my hash was getting messed up.